# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm learning a bit of PHP.  It's supposed to print 0, however I get an error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in...

```
<?php 
$json = '[{"assetref":"","qty":0,"raw":0}]';

$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'qty'}; // Result 0 

?>
```

Comment: solutions "$obj[0]->{'qty'};"

Comment: Yes, `print_r($obj);` to see. And why not just `$obj[0]->qty;`

Comment: @MiguelAngelCastillo Aside from the array issue, the complex syntax `->{'qty'}` isn't necessary for property names like qty. `->qty` will work just fine. You only need to use the brackets if the JSON includes identifiers that aren't valid PHP as property names. (Like "asset-qty" for example.)

Answer (score 1):

The brackets on the outside of your JSON string are causing it to be an object inside of an array.

You can access the object by specifying which array member you want with `$obj[0]->{'qty'};`

OR change your json string so it instantiates into an object directly.

```
$json = '{"assetref":"","qty":0,"raw":0}';
```

Comment: @AbraCadaver Because copy/paste, I assume. I didn't change it when I edited to format the code, because it seemed like an overstep, and it does still work even though it's pointless in this case.